# How to log queries to database drivers?

Tags: sql, database, logging, go

I am trying to write a simple Database application in go which access multiple data servers, some MySQL, MSSQL and SqlLite3.
I am using the "database/sql" package to access them.

```golang
db, err := sql.Open(driver, dataSourceName)
result, err := db.Exec(
    "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)",
    "gopher",
    27,
)
```

I need to log the SQL queries to the individual servers for debugging and auditing.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to use the servers logging facilities, the obvious solution would be to simply log all queries as they are made.

```
db, err := sql.Open(driver, dataSourceName)
log.Println(dataSourceName, "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)", "gopher", 27)
result, err := db.Exec(
    "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)",
    "gopher",
    27,
)
```

This is the basic solution for your problem. You can refine it in multiple ways:

- Create a `log.Logger` exclusively for your queries, so you can direct it to a particular output destination
- Wrap the said `log.Logger` and the `sql.DB` objects in a special struct that will log queries as they are done

Here is a rough example of the said struct:

```
type DB struct {
    db *sql.DB
    dsn string
    log *log.Logger
}

func NewDB(driver, dsn string, log *log.Logger) (*DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open(driver, dsn)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &DB {
        db: db,
        dsn: dsn,
        log: log,
    }
}

func (d DB) Exec(query string, args ...interface{}) (sql.Result, err) {
    d.log.Println(dsn, query, args)
    return d.db.Exec(query, args...)
}
```

And how you would use it:

```
l := log.New(os.Stdout, "[sql]", log.LstdFlags)

db, _ := NewDB(driver, dataSourceName, l)
result, _ := db.Exec(
    "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)",
    "gopher",
    27,
)
```

Obviously, you can refined this design again, by adding error reporting, duration of the queries, etc.

Comment: So the first option is an obvious shortcut, but the repeat of query has issue because if the developer edits the Exec string and not the Println string, there will be a discrepancy and defeat the purpose.

Your second solution seems to be the answer. I need to write a wrapper package for accessing DB which does logging and other custom behavior for me. Thank you for the idea.

Basic reason why I don't want to depend on the DB server logging is that I don't have access to some of them and secondly, it would be great to have it in a centralized place.

Comment: The bonus of the struct approach is that you can use an interface in your methods, which will simplify unit-testing…

Answer (score 2):

There is now a solution for that without having to wrap `sql.DB` with a wrapper that adds the logging.

[sqldblogger](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/simukti/sqldb-logger) facilitates this without needing to change existing `sql.DB` code.

Answer (score 0):

To add logging capabilities to `sql.DB`, you can either make a wrapper for `sql.DB` or use the `driver` interface.

For a driver you would wrap an existing driver and add logging hooks to each of the ways of executing queries. Thats what I've done in the QueryPulse driver.