# Count number of queries on database in Golang?

Tags: mysql, go

I am attempting to count the number of queries that are run against the database in a request against my Golang API server. This is in order to optimize + find bottlenecks in our API.

An example of how to do this in Django is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556139/get-sql-query-count-during-a-django-shell-session).

Any idea if there is a simple way to do this in Golang?

Comment: The [`expvar`](https://golang.org/pkg/expvar/) package is available specifically for in-app metrics.

Answer (score 4):

In order to find bottlenecks I would suggest going straight to the MySQL database and enabling the slow query log and slowly setting the [long_query_time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) down to a low millisecond value.

Use tools like [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html) to help digest these to get a frequency of like queries. Attack those as slow queries that need fixing and then set a lower value.

The actual count of the queries on each isn't actually that useful.

When attacking the problem from a go point of view measuring the API response time of each interface will help you look holisticly at the service.

Comment: Also see [flame graphs in go programs](http://brendanjryan.com/golang/profiling/2018/02/28/profiling-go-applications.html). You'll quickly see calls in the go application that are waiting on SQL responses but also see time consuming areas of your application.

Answer (score 3):

No easy solution that I'm aware of.

You could wrap your db in your own struct, and then implement `Exec()` or whichever function you use directly on that struct. Your function would just call the database one, and count it however you see fit.

A similar example, but with a logger, can be found here:
[How to log queries to database drivers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270501/how-to-log-queries-to-database-drivers)